# Why doesn't this number regex (with alternations) match as expected?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the following strings:

```
9
9.
9.5
.5
```

This is what I've produced so far to accomplish this:

```
(?<acreage>(?(\d+)((\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+)))
```

When I pass in 9.5, it returns NULL and .5 for acreage.  I need it to pass back 9.5.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `|` is an "alternation" (or "one of"), not an "if-then-else" (or "do when ..")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have four situations:

1. Match something like `x`
2. Match something like `x.y`
3. Match something like `x.`
4. Match something like `.y`

So here you go:

```
\d+\.\d+|\d+\.?|\.d+
```

You can get rid of either of the last two possibilities by making digits in the first group optional, *but not both*. For instance:

```
\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?
```

Or, with a match group:

```
(?<acreage>\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?)
```

Comment: I will go with parsimony and say that I like this solution the most.  Legion's solution is cool, though.

Answer (score 1):

use this regular expression

`^(?=\.?\d+\.?\d*)\d*\.?\d*$`

or

`^(\d+\.\d*)|(\d*\.\d+)|(\d+)$`

Comment: That one person removed their answer, but it was pretty close.  Just one modification: (\d+\.?\d*)|(\d*\.\d+)